# Sharing PyCharm environment across devices

Tags: pycharm

Quite often I switch between laptop and a desktop machine.

I used to work with VIM  and Tmux which were installed on a small VPS instance. That allowed me easily switch between computers keeping all my vim tabs, workspace, etc the same.

Is it possible to achieve something like that with PyCharm? Does it have any functionality for sharing it's session? If it can save it's state probably it's possible to keep in Dropbox.

Answer (score 1):

The **.idea** directory in each of the pycharm project dir contains all configurations related to that project (true for other jetbrains tools as well).

Here are some references that may help:

- https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/managing-projects-under-version-control.html
- https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23393067
- [Should the .idea folder be kept under source control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362816/should-the-idea-folder-be-kept-under-source-control)

Comment: As I understand this will only keep the project settings. But the open tabs and cursor positions are not preserved. Am I wrong?

Comment: I'm not using vim tabs, but the last files I had open in the editor windows (with vim emulation) open in the same position for every project I had open when I exited pycharm. IMHO even if not perfect, it's fairly close to restoring the session. What it's missing (or at least I didn't dig enough into it) would be to automatically re-run the development server (and maybe restore the previous run session logs).