# What to gitignore from the .idea folder?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, gitignore, webstorm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Intellij Idea 9/10, what folders to check into (or not check into) source control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041154/intellij-idea-9-10-what-folders-to-check-into-or-not-check-into-source-contro)

I started using WebStorm for web development and am not sure what to add and what to exclude from our Git repository. Clearly some files inside the `.idea` folder are meant to be version controlled like the external library settings (`jsLibraryMappings.xml`) but others will probably change very often and are developer-specific (e.g., `workspace.xml`).

What is the recommended `.gitignore` pattern for WebStorm / IntelliJ IDEA?

P.S. There are already questions about this but usually focus only on whether to include the whole `.idea` folder or whether to fully exclude it. I think some of the files inside the `.idea` folder should be version controlled while others shouldn't and I'm trying to find out which ones.

Comment: I think, that put IDE files into versioning system is bad idea. Your project will be more tied to particular IDE and you can bring problems for users of other IDEs. I had a few projects with IDE files in VCS and I faced complications. Now I have in VCS just maven files and IDEA generate project files and everything is fine.

Comment: @chalimartines I prefer to have everything required for build in the repository. As we don't use Maven and also use a single IDE, it would be a complication NOT to have `.idea` files in VCS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intellij Idea 9/10, what folders to check into (or not check into) source control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041154/intellij-idea-9-10-what-folders-to-check-into-or-not-check-into-source-contro)

Comment: In latest versions, there will be created an .gitignore files inside the .idea folder, what already contains a bunch of good ignore rules (to keep files that should be shared, and exclude user specific stuff)

Answer (score 556, accepted):

[The official support page](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839-How-to-manage-projects-under-Version-Control-Systems) should answer your question.

So in your `.gitignore` you might ignore the files ending with `.iws`, and the `workspace.xml` and `tasks.xml` files.

Comment: The doc recommends "share all the .iml module files", so a .gitignore with the following two lines should be fine:  .idea/workspace.xml
.idea/tasks.xml

Comment: @KevinOrtman this does not seem to work if the project is not at the root of your repository?

Comment: The correct syntax seems to be `*/.idea/workspace.xml
*/.idea/tasks.xml`

Comment: @KevinOrtman, the answer pertains to two different file formats. `*.iws` files are ignored when using the `.ipr` project format, and `workspace.xml` and `tasks.xml` files are ignored when using the `.idea` project format.

Comment: What about `.idea/watcherTasks.xml`? This file contains very user-dependent settings like paths to executables.

Comment: What to do if I'm the only person in team who is using Rubymine others are on Sublime Text?

Comment: A better syntax is `**/.idea/workspace.xml **/.idea/tasks.xml`

Comment: I generally ignore the entire folder - seeing as I am pretty much the only one that uses such an IDE in my workplace.

Comment: The updated official Jetbrains link is: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839-How-to-manage-projects-under-Version-Control-Systems

Comment: In my latest version of PHPStorm (2016.2.1) I'm getting a `.idea/copyright/` directory. So I now add a `**/.idea/copyright/` line to my `.gitignore`.

Comment: I had to also exclude the file _.idea/vcs.xml_ for it to work.

Comment: Based on https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000661950-A-lot-of-files-in-contentModel-xml the contentModel file should also be ignored using **/.idea/contentModel.xml (I think that it is Rider specific). It contains absolute paths.

Comment: What's the benefit of committing the idea folder? I will just continue ignoring it after reading two more additions of files that need ignored unless someone can give me a good reason to keep it version controlled.

Comment: so you can share with coworkers project-wide settings like code style, folder types, etc

Comment: Note that since version 2019.1, IntelliJ can [automatically add the right config files to version control](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-projects.html#share-project-through-vcs).

Comment: In can other extensions (like SonarLint) adds extra files to .idea, you can get a more targeted .gitignore like this:

**/.idea/**
!**/.idea/**/*.xml
!**/.idea/**/*.iml
**/.idea/workspace.xml
**/.idea/tasks.xml

Comment: JetBrains now recommends to exclude the `shelf` folder and a file called `usage.statistics.xml` as well.

Answer (score 337):

I just want to present a more recent alternative. There is an online tool that generates `.gitignore` files based on operating systems, IDEs and programming languages that you might be using.

[gitignore.io](http://www.gitignore.io)

---

**Disclaimer**: Do not copy this file, copy the file generated by the website instead, they do a good job on keeping it updated. This is just an example.

The file generated for `IntelliJ` contains the following

```
# Created by https://www.gitignore.io/api/intellij

### Intellij ###
# Covers JetBrains IDEs: IntelliJ, RubyMine, PhpStorm, AppCode, PyCharm, CLion, Android Studio and Webstorm
# Reference: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839

# User-specific stuff:
.idea/workspace.xml
.idea/tasks.xml
.idea/dictionaries
.idea/vcs.xml
.idea/jsLibraryMappings.xml

# Sensitive or high-churn files:
.idea/dataSources.ids
.idea/dataSources.xml
.idea/dataSources.local.xml
.idea/sqlDataSources.xml
.idea/dynamic.xml
.idea/uiDesigner.xml

# Gradle:
.idea/gradle.xml
.idea/libraries

# Mongo Explorer plugin:
.idea/mongoSettings.xml

## File-based project format:
*.iws

## Plugin-specific files:

# IntelliJ
/out/

# mpeltonen/sbt-idea plugin
.idea_modules/

# JIRA plugin
atlassian-ide-plugin.xml

# Crashlytics plugin (for Android Studio and IntelliJ)
com_crashlytics_export_strings.xml
crashlytics.properties
crashlytics-build.properties
fabric.properties

### Intellij Patch ###
# Comment Reason: https://github.com/joeblau/gitignore.io/issues/186#issuecomment-215987721

# *.iml
# modules.xml
```

Comment: "By default they suggest you ignore everything from `.idea/`" - not any more. Currently generated .gitignore doesn't have the `.idea/` entry.

Comment: Why would you ignore `.idea/dictionaries` outright?

Comment: @Rhymoid I don't know why specifically since I am not the one proposing the `.gitignore`. I am just showing the tool that does it. My guess is that it is a personal file. You can add stuff in your dictionary that might not be valid for others. Specially when you are cleaning up LINT messages. I believe that if you agree amongst your teammates you might add it to your git repo.

Comment: I intended to use the generic 'you', sorry. But with the parallels it has to linting, it totally makes sense to have them in a source repo, because the entries will in fact apply to everyone: the dictionaries are specific to the content of the project! For instance, when working on a parser for C, *everyone* will run into the problem that the word "punctuator" is falsely marked as a misspelling... unless you share the dictionary.

Comment: @user824425 IntelliJ says to **be careful about the user dictionaries folder (to avoid conflicts if other developer has the same name)** - see https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839-How-to-manage-projects-under-Version-Control-Systems

Answer (score 55):

For a couple of years I was a supporter of using a specific `.gitignore` for IntelliJ with [this suggested configuration](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/JetBrains.gitignore).

**Not anymore.**

IntelliJ is updated quite frequently, internal config file specs change more often than I would like and JetBrains flagship excels at auto-configuring itself based on maven/gradle/etc build files.

So my suggestion would be to leave **all editor config files out of project** and have users configure editor to their liking. Things like code styling can and should be configured at build level; say using **[Google Code Style](https://github.com/google/google-java-format)** or **[CheckStyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/)** directly on Maven/Gradle/sbt/etc.

This ensures consistency and leaves editor files out of source code that, in my personal opinion, is where they should be.

Comment: That's exactly my point, We should not hassle around `.gitignore` just for JB as I have explained in my answer.

Comment: Somehow I ended up with a default .gitignore that would not simply excluding the whole .idea folder and my changes was often polluted with nonsense. Just ignore the whole folder.

Answer (score 33):

https://www.gitignore.io/api/jetbrains

Created by https://www.gitignore.io/api/jetbrains

```
### JetBrains ###
# Covers JetBrains IDEs: IntelliJ, RubyMine, PhpStorm, AppCode, PyCharm, CLion, Android Studio and Webstorm
# Reference: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839

# User-specific stuff:
.idea/workspace.xml
.idea/tasks.xml
.idea/dictionaries
.idea/vcs.xml
.idea/jsLibraryMappings.xml

# Sensitive or high-churn files:
.idea/dataSources.ids
.idea/dataSources.xml
.idea/dataSources.local.xml
.idea/sqlDataSources.xml
.idea/dynamic.xml
.idea/uiDesigner.xml

# Gradle:
.idea/gradle.xml
.idea/libraries

# Mongo Explorer plugin:
.idea/mongoSettings.xml

## File-based project format:
*.iws

## Plugin-specific files:

# IntelliJ
/out/

# mpeltonen/sbt-idea plugin
.idea_modules/

# JIRA plugin
atlassian-ide-plugin.xml

# Crashlytics plugin (for Android Studio and IntelliJ)
com_crashlytics_export_strings.xml
crashlytics.properties
crashlytics-build.properties
fabric.properties

### JetBrains Patch ###
# Comment Reason: https://github.com/joeblau/gitignore.io/issues/186#issuecomment-215987721

# *.iml
# modules.xml
# .idea/misc.xml 
# *.ipr
```

Comment: OK! if you want to ingore something, you can go to [https://www.gitignore.io/](https://www.gitignore.io/ ) , it can be very helpful for you to easily find what you wanna!

Comment: This is helpful but it would better if you just linked to the file - there are already differences in the online version.

Comment: Why not just do `.idea/*`? Saves a lot of lines.

Comment: @Hackinet  that's depends on your situation, ignore all files with the `*` symbol or just only needs ignore some specials files.

Answer (score 22):

Github uses the following .gitignore for their programs

https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/JetBrains.gitignore

```
# Covers JetBrains IDEs: IntelliJ, RubyMine, PhpStorm, AppCode, PyCharm, CLion, Android Studio and WebStorm
# Reference: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839

# User-specific stuff
.idea/**/workspace.xml
.idea/**/tasks.xml
.idea/**/usage.statistics.xml
.idea/**/dictionaries
.idea/**/shelf

# Generated files
.idea/**/contentModel.xml

# Sensitive or high-churn files
.idea/**/dataSources/
.idea/**/dataSources.ids
.idea/**/dataSources.local.xml
.idea/**/sqlDataSources.xml
.idea/**/dynamic.xml
.idea/**/uiDesigner.xml
.idea/**/dbnavigator.xml

# Gradle
.idea/**/gradle.xml
.idea/**/libraries

# Gradle and Maven with auto-import
# When using Gradle or Maven with auto-import, you should exclude module files,
# since they will be recreated, and may cause churn.  Uncomment if using
# auto-import.
# .idea/modules.xml
# .idea/*.iml
# .idea/modules

# CMake
cmake-build-*/

# Mongo Explorer plugin
.idea/**/mongoSettings.xml

# File-based project format
*.iws

# IntelliJ
out/

# mpeltonen/sbt-idea plugin
.idea_modules/

# JIRA plugin
atlassian-ide-plugin.xml

# Cursive Clojure plugin
.idea/replstate.xml

# Crashlytics plugin (for Android Studio and IntelliJ)
com_crashlytics_export_strings.xml
crashlytics.properties
crashlytics-build.properties
fabric.properties

# Editor-based Rest Client
.idea/httpRequests

# Android studio 3.1+ serialized cache file
.idea/caches/build_file_checksums.ser
```

Answer (score 17):

You can simply ignore all of them by adding `.idea/*` to the `.gitignore` file.

Comment: I disagree. When you do this, you exclude a.. runConfigurations too, so you can not share important tasks for building/minifing css ect.

Answer (score 4):

in my case `/**/.idea/*` works well

Comment: but this exclude e.g. the runConfiguration for tasks in this project too

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the [support page](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839-How-to-manage-projects-under-Version-Control-Systems), starting with version 2019.1, IntelliJ is capable of adding everything that needs sharing to Version Control [automatically](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-projects.html#share-project-through-vcs).

This is great since the IDE will add just the necessary files to Git in two steps:

1. Open the project with IntelliJ and wait a moment until the following pop to shows up in the bottom-right corner
2. Select "Always Add"

[image: IntelliJ menu pop-up says "Project configurations files can be added to Git"]

Alternatively you can select "View Files" and then add them manually.

Comment: Exactly. All .idea projects these days automatically create a .gitignore inside the .idea tree. You can leave it as is, and also have another more global .gitignore for the entire repo with any other stuff you want git to ignore, and git will pick them both up and apply them correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `.idea*` to the `.gitignore` file, it should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ignore files without adding them to `.gitignore`, you may wish to utilize `.git/info/exclude` -> I've added `/.idea/` to my `.git/info/exclude` file. (Easiest solution for me, operating from within pycharm.)

Further reading: [When would you use .git/info/exclude instead of .gitignore to exclude files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22906851/when-would-you-use-git-info-exclude-instead-of-gitignore-to-exclude-files)

Answer (score 0):

While using gradle I only need to keep settings.gradle and build.gradle Any editor structure, along with gradle wrapper, are being rebuild on loading the project and custom IDE settings are pulled from synchronisation plugin.

Answer (score -1):

While maintaining the proper `.gitignore` file is helpful, I found this alternate approach is way cleaner and easier to use.

- Create dummy folder `my_project` and inside that `git clone my_real_project` the actual project repo.
- Now while opening the project in IDE (Intellij/Pycharm) open the folder `my_project` and mark `my_project/my_real_project` as the VCS root.
- You can see `my_project/.idea` wouldn't pollute your git repo because it  happily lives outside the git repo which is what you want. This way your `.gitignore` files stays clean as well.

This approach works better due to the below reasons.

1 - `.gitignore` file stays clean and we don't have to insert lines related to JetBrains products, that file is better used for binaries and libraries and autogen contents.

2 - Intellij keeps updating their projects and the files inside `.idea` keep changing every significant release from JB. What this means is we have to keep updating our `.gitignore` accordingly which is not an ideal use of time.

3 - Intellij has the flawed pattern here, most editors Atom, VS Code, Eclipse... nobody stores their IDE contents right inside project root. JB shouldn't be an exception either. It's the onus of Jetbrains to keep those files tracked outside project root. They have to refrain from polluting VCS root. This approach does just that. The `.idea` folder is kept outside the `PROJECT_ROOT`

Hope this helps.

Comment: This answer is completely misleading. `/.idea` in .gitignore works fine; Usually the problem will be solved after by this command: `git rm --cached -r .idea`

Comment: `/.idea` doesn't work, You can check other answers and the official guidelines from JB too

Comment: I don't understand why you think you need to keep your .gitignore clean. But you can always just put this in your user git config rather than going through this extra dummy folder approach.

Comment: @ChristopherBarber You don't understand because you haven't met with the problem yet. When I meant keeping gitignore clean I considered constantly changing it file for something not the fault of the developer just because Jetbrains keep adding files or changing filenames.

Comment: Yes, but if you want to ignore all of the .idea files you only need to add `/.idea/` to your .gitignore file once and forget about it. Or you can do the same thing in your user `.gitconfig` and not bother with this dummy folder approach.

Comment: While I relate to what you want to do just put `.idea` folder on .gitignore and be done with it. Using your solution, instead of "polluting" git' ignore file you are actually "polluting" your workspace with unnecessary folders just for the sake of using JetBrains. No need to do that!

Comment: @ChristopherBarber adding `/.idea/` doesn't work as one imagines, otherwise numerous answers in this thread and other threads are simply vain. Even Jetbrains' recommend `.gitignore` list contains explicit list of individual `.xml` files.

Comment: I don't know what you imagine. But adding `/.idea` ignores all of the files in that directory. If that is what you want, you are done. If you only want to ignore some files, then you have to list them individually, but then your answer would also be useless.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this approach either; it is much more of a burden than necessary. You can add `.idea` to your global Git ignore as mentioned in other comments, or just ignore `.idea` altogether, since the IDE now produces a `.gitignore` file in the `.idea` directory when it is created.

Comment: You don't need this solution until you do.

Comment: No idea why this one got downvoted. I totally agree that IDE stuff must never be .gitignore-d and committed to the repository just because _someone_ thinks this is the only IDE in use for _this_ particular project. What if someone prefers Eclipse? `.gitignore` should only contain files that can be generated during the build, not ones that cover someone else's preferences for IDE. To all of the downvoters, learn what `.git/info/exclude` and `core.excludesfile` are.

Comment: @user12232870 the amount of lines other people suggest to ignore for `.idea/` related files are indeed too untidy

Comment: The idea is quite nice, the only problem could be, if your project contains files that are expected to be in project root. E.g. composer.json

Answer (score -11):

- Remove .idea folder

  ```
  $rm -R .idea/
  ```
- Add rule

  ```
  $echo ".idea/*" >> .gitignore
  ```
- Commit .gitignore file

  ```
  $git commit -am "remove .idea"
  ```
- Next commit will be ok

Comment: ignoring the idea folder is fine as not everyone uses them, and they are not part of your code - you (hopefully) don't need them on production, for instance.

Comment: ignoring is fine, but removing is less of a good idea. It contains information for your local workspace.

Comment: I'm surprised this is down-voted.
Seams to be the best answer here!

Comment: The answer is downvoted because it doesn't answer the question. You also don't have to remove your .idea folder in order to gitignore it.

Comment: @ChristopherBarber you need to remove it from git origin though

Comment: @ChristopherBarber And this is not the right way.