# Difference between .git/info/exclude and .gitignore

Tags: git, ignore

When I cloned a repo from GitLab to local, it along with source code it also pulled a file in the root folder caller `.gitignore`. 
There is also a folder called `.git` which contains a directory in `info` contains a file called `exclude`. 
Which one is the one that does the ignore (to me ignore and exclude mean the same)? Is it the ignore or exclude?

Comment: Ignore what vs exclude what? Both files serve a purpose, but you are not being clear about what purpose you are looking for.

Comment: You should not touch whatever is in `.git`. `.gitignore` is something you are providing. The `.git` files are not supposed to be manually modified.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I think the question is very clear. newb7777 just want to know what the purpose is of the two different files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When would you use .git/info/exclude instead of .gitignore to exclude files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22906851/when-would-you-use-git-info-exclude-instead-of-gitignore-to-exclude-files)

Comment: @klutt. I suppose you are right. I should have voted to close as a dupe instead of unclear.

Comment: @EugeneSh. - That advice is not applicable to the `info/exclude` file

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Although the question is not about which is better ".gitignore" or "info/exclude", one thing to note is "gitignore" is instantaneous than exclude. It takes effect immediately during stating process versus "gitignore" takes effect in the beginning when you clone a repository.

Answer (score 30):

They both contain "ignore rules" - filename patterns for which matching untracked files should be ignored.

The difference is that rules in `.gitignore` are shared through the repo, whreas rules in `info/exclude` are not.  So if for some reason you need to *locally* ignore certain paths in a single clone, you would use `info/exclude`; but if a path should be ignored in *all* clones, you would use `.gitignore`

Comment: To be clear: the `info/exclude` file you got when you cloned the repo *is not* a copy of the corresponding file on the origin.  It is newly-created by git as a place to put rules specific to the new clone.

Comment: Yes that is correct. The exclude is newly created when i clone the repo from remote repo. `.gitignore` is the one from GitLab.

Comment: if you have both files in the local repo, `.gitignore` and `info/exclude` which one takes precedence? This situation may arise when you are cloning someone else repository to your local repository and have updated your `info/exclude` file with your exclude list.

Comment: `.gitignore` takes higher precedence.