# git clean deletes files in gitignore, db/production.sqlite3 is lost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, gitignore, git-clean

I was trying to remove an untracked file from a branch that I deleted, and instead I accidentally deleted untracked and tracked files... including apparently the dev and production databases!!!

What should I do?  `git clone` and start over from last commit?

```
Thomass-MacBook-Pro:livebytransit tomb$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    app/assets/javascripts/.txt
    app/assets/javascripts/shared/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
Thomass-MacBook-Pro:livebytransit tomb$ git clean -n
Would remove app/assets/javascripts/.txt
Thomass-MacBook-Pro:livebytransit tomb$ git clean -fx
Removing app/assets/javascripts/.txt
Removing db/development.sqlite3
Removing db/production.sqlite3
Removing log/development.log
Removing log/production.log
```

Comment: Untracked files are, well, untracked. Git does not have them. Restore them from your backup.

Comment: Unfortunately for me I don't have a backup hard drive, and I am the only person who works on this app.  If I run rake db:migrate, would that theoretically recreate my databases?

Comment: That will perhaps restore the database structure, but supposedly not your data.

Comment: Yes, I ran rake db:migrate and restored the structure.  Now running rake db:seed to reload the data....my app should be back in business in 12 hours after all the data has loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, `git clean` can only delete untracked files. It can not delete a tracked file (even if you've just done a `git add` on a file, it becomes untouchable by `git clean`). Any untracked files, by definition, are not recoverable by git since git just doesn't know about them. In case you had them tracked previously, you could [check out a past version of the file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/215731/1860929).

Secondly, The 2 commands you ran are not identical: the `-x` flag instructs git to remove all untracked files (even those ignored by [various `.gitignore`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22906950/1860929)s). This is what has caused your problem.

While your first command (`git clean -n`) showed you files it would clean ignoring the ones specified by `gitignore` rules, the second one(`git clean -fx`) included those as well for deletion due to the `-x` flag. As such, *all untracked files* are deleted - whether ignored by `gitignore` or not.

In future, you should execute: `git clean -f` only, if you want the desired behaviour.

For now, you should get hold of the `db/*.sqlite` files from a backup/some other developer/via database migrations if needed. The `*.log` files should hopefully get automagically generated by your dev setup, if not, just create empty files with the name.

Quoting from the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean):

> `$ man git-clean`
>
> Cleans the working tree by recursively removing files that are not under version control, starting from the current directory.
>
> `-x`
>
> Don’t use the standard ignore rules read from .gitignore (per directory) and $GIT_DIR/info/exclude, but do still use the ignore
>              rules given with -e options. This allows removing all untracked files, including build products.
>
> `-n, --dry-run`
>
> Don’t actually remove anything, just show what would be done.
>
> `-f, --force`
>
> If the Git configuration variable clean.requireForce is not set to false, git clean will refuse to delete files or directories
>              unless given -f, -n or -i

Comment: Thank you for your answer, much appreciated. I don't have a backup and I'm the only person working on this.  When you say to get hold of the *.sqlite3 files through migrations, is that the same as running rake db:migrate to recreate my databases?  Also, my database.yml shows sqlite3 for both development and production, but I am on Heroku and therefore the production db is postgresql.  Perhaps the loss of the production.sqlite3 is a non-issue?

Comment: @tbone yes and yes. I meant using rake db:migrations to create database locally, and since you are on heroku, the production.sqlite3 that was deleted is only the local file - it doesn't have any relation with heroku postgresql.