# When would you use .git/info/exclude instead of ~/.gitignore (core.excludesFile) to exclude files?

Tags: git, version-control, gitignore

I am little bit confused as to when would you use `.git/info/exclude` instead of `~/.gitignore (core.excludesFile)` to exclude files? I am clear when to use `.gitignore` file present in project repository which is specific to that project, version-controlled and shared with other repo via clone but I am unable to understand difference between the above two somewhat user specific files to be ignored.

Thus, I am looking for difference between `~/.gitignore` and `.git/info/exclude` and not between `.gitignore (project dir)` and `.git/info/exclude`.

UPDATE: I am unable to think specific usage of `.git/info/exclude` as whatever files I want to ignore either fall in `.gitignore` or `~/.gitignore`. It would really help if somebody can give an example for pattern/file that should specifically be included in `.git/info/exclude`.

Comment: No that is not what I am looking for. I already know the difference between these two. .gitignore in project dir and ~/.gitignore are different files.

Comment: I am looking for difference between ~/.gitignore and .git/info/exclude and not between .gitignore (project dir) and .git/info/exclude.

Comment: Isn’t that what the question talks about? The location of the .gitignore shouldn’t matter (apart from some specifics)

Comment: `~/.gitignore` this applies to all repos and this `.gitignore` is repo specific

Comment: No, the .gitignore file at these two locations server entire different purpose. Feel free to see the same in the official documentation https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Comment: @SaurabhPBhandari my question is how `~./gitignore` is different from `.git/info/exclude`. It would really help if you give an example. Thanks in advance

Comment: I am unable to think specific usage of `.git/info/exclude` as whatever files I want to ignore either fall in `.gitignore` or `~/.gitignore`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Placing a file name or pattern in your global ignore file (`~/.gitignore` or `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/ignore`) will suppress complaints about it in all repositories.  Placing the same name or pattern in the per-repository ignore file (`.git/info/exclude`) will suppress complaints only for that one repository.

Neither of these is inherently superior or inferior; they're just *different*.  It's worth noting that ancient Git supported only the in-repository `.gitignore` and `.git/info/exclude` files, i.e., had no per-user, global `~/.gitignore`.

If you personally use an editor that makes backup files whose name ends with (say) `$` instead of `.bak` or `.~`, and everyone else doesn't (and the everyone-else's backup files are already in a committed `.gitignore`), you might put `*$` in your personal `~/.gitignore`.  If you only use this editor with this one project, it might make more sense to put this in `.git/info/exclude`.

If the project itself makes a lot of to-be-ignored files, it makes sense to put these names into `.gitignore` files that are committed into the project, but if there is some reason that this *cannot* be done, it then makes sense to put these patterns into `.git/info/exclude`: they should not be ignored in other projects.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborated answer. I understand your point, however, in general (leaving some special cases), is it safe to assume that `.gitignore` and `~/.gitignore` is sufficient to specify what should be ignored?

Comment: @DevendraSwami What are the concerns that it’s not?

Comment: @evolutionxbox none as far as I know. Just want to know if I am missing something. Like `.git/info/exclude` is nice to have but doesn't offer any real gains. It might also be a legacy thing as the ancient git doesn't have global `~/.gitignore`.

Comment: I don't know whether, if Git were being designed today *and* they thought to include `~/.gitignore` in the initial design, they—the Git designers—would bother to define a `.git/info/excludes` file at all. Historically, though, that was where one stuck editor backups if the maintainers of some project wouldn't put your editor backup patterns in their repo's `.gitignore` files.

Comment: @torek. Thanks. Completely agree.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore),

> Patterns which are specific to a particular repository but which do
>   not need to be shared with other related repositories (e.g., auxiliary
>   files that live inside the repository but are specific to one user’s
>   workflow) should go into the **$GIT_DIR/info/exclude** file.
>
> Patterns which a user wants Git to ignore in all situations (e.g.,
>   backup or temporary files generated by the user’s editor of choice)
>   generally go into a file specified by core.excludesFile in the user’s
>   **~/.gitconfig**.

If you are working on an IDE, it usually has IDE specific files such as project settings, workspace settings etc. These files are user and repository (different IDE for different projects...) specific. Such files can be excluded using `$GIT_DIR/info/exclude` file.

With respect to this `~/.gitconfig`, the editor might leave some backup or temporary files such as nano keeping swap files in the directory during editing , so such files should be ignored globally for all repositories in the local system.

> Still the question remains; is it safe to assume that .gitignore and
>   ~/.gitignore is sufficient to specify what should be ignored?

`.gitignore` should not be a problem since it is repository specific, however `~/.gitignore` might be a problem, consider a situation where a file is globally ignored using `~/.gitingore` for all the local repositories, and it turns out that the file was a necessary component for another repository, in that case `$GIT_DIR/info/exclude` should be used.

Comment: Can you give an example what should be specifically included in $GIT_DIR/info/exclude file and not in the other two?

Comment: isn't it safe to specify these files in `~/.gitignore` as then you need not to specify them for each repository as same IDE is usually used for more than one project.

Comment: Still the question remains; is it safe to assume that `.gitignore` and `~/.gitignore` is sufficient to specify what should be ignored? Since, the example given above can be included in `~/.gitignore`.