# How to stash the .gitignore files and directory and apply them whenever I want

Tags: git

Assume this a structure of top most commit

```
  --src
      --app
         --node_modules
         --code
```

In older commit the `code` does not live inside `app` rather it lives inside `work` and there is no `app` folder. so when I checkout to that commit this will be my structure

```
   --src
       --app
          --node_modules
       --work
           --code
```

Since `node_modules` is a `.gitignore` directory. It wont be removed. As you can see when you have lot of directory like this there will be **huge screen space** taken by directory which we dont need.

My doubt is that is there any way I can remove those directory and add then add those when I want, in this case it will be when I am in topmost commit. Just like how `git stash` works?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You could `git clone` to some other directory before your `git checkout`. Disk space is cheap

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch isnt `git clone` just clones the repo. I am not really sure how this is helpfull

Comment: Just have *two* copies of your git-ed repository in two different directories.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch then I should remove those files manually?

Comment: Did you spend hours in reading the [documentation of `git`](http://git-scm.com/doc) ?

Comment: Can you explain your issue with these folders ? Do they take space on *disk* or in the output of *git status* ?

Comment: If you want to always ignore `node_modules` folders, you can add `node_modules` to one of the global ignore files. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/22906950/86072

Comment: @LeGEC They too take up lot of spaces. But thats not my problem, my problem is purely convenience. In my repo I have almost 10 - 12 directory which contains its own node_modules.  But in older commit, I grouped all of the code into a single directory and they shared single node_modules. So when I go back to older commit, those 10-12 directory are still present and taking up screen space.  I dont want that, I could just delete all those directory manually but then when I go to top most commit, I have to download those node_modules again. Which are huge and takes lot of time.

Comment: It's not at all clear to me what you really want here, but note that if you run `git stash -a`, this *commits* the untracked-and-ignored files, then uses `git clean` to remove them (now that they are safely committed). This does not save much disk space at all (in practice it may need *more* space temporarily as soon as the files get unpacked later) and these three-commit stashes are hard to use, but that will get them removed from your working tree.

Comment: I think I understood your issue. The word "space" in your question is misleading, since most readers will understand "disk space" : could you rephrase that sentence, to better explain your issue ? (`ls` will still list all directories, your visual file explorer will display them ... )

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have a git repository like https://github.com/RefPerSys/RefPerSys (for the [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/) project)

You could do (on Linux)

```
git clone  https://github.com/RefPerSys/RefPerSys ~/RefPerSys_blue
```

then

```
git clone  https://github.com/RefPerSys/RefPerSys ~/RefPerSys_red
```

and now you have two copies of the same repository, one in  directory `~/RefPerSys_blue/` and another in directory `~/RefPerSys_red/` both inside your home directory `~/`

Later, you might

```
 cd ~/RefPerSys_red/
 git checkout 1b783efb1d17
```

and have, in `~/RefPerSys_red/`, the commit 1b783efb1d17

### Disk space is cheap, your time is less cheap.

Comment: thanks for the reply but thats not the solution I need, so i thought my question might not be clear, so I edited it

Comment: Why are you forbidden to have two copies of your repository on your hard disk? This should be written in your question!

Comment: I am not forbidden from having two copies of same repository, but how having two repository is going to solve my problem ?, having two repository wont remove the `node_modules` directory

Comment: @Nivekithan: waht this answer suggest is : check the older version of your repo in the second clone, if you manipulate only the older version in that clone, its layout on disk will match what you expect.