# Git not working properly in Android studio, not showing changes for XML files

Tags: git, android-studio

I have been having an issue, git does not recognize changes on any XML file on Android Studio, for example, androidManifest.xml, or any XML file on the res folder. I have used Android Studio as my Git client, I have changed it thinking that the problem was a bug on Android Studio, and now I am using GitHub Desktop, but the problem persists.

The problem is that any change I make to an XML file is not taken, so I keep losing time and work.

I have been looking for a solution, but I can't find a solution anywhere, any ideas?

This is an update of the initial post, I did nothing, just open the .gitignore file, which has only one line:

```
/build
```

Also, I opened the file .git/info/exclude, it has a few lines of comments, nothing else and that was it. Then I realized that the changes on every single XML file started to show on GitHub Desktop and also on Android Studio Git-client.

Comment: Just verifying you checked your `.gitignore` file.

Comment: the file .gitignore file is in my <project root dir>/app/.gitignore, it has just one line:

/build

Comment: So you have no `.gitignore` in <project root dir>? I would also see if [When would you use .git/info/exclude instead of .gitignore to exclude files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22906851/295004) applies to your project/environment. Also note: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22906950/295004

Comment: Hi Morrison, thanks for the tip, I still don't know why git does not show changes on any XML file, I have been looking up and down, and I do not find any .gitignore file, nor .git/info/exclude that had a line indicating so, but this gave me ideas to start playing with .gitignore.

Answer (score 0):

See what would be removed when cleaning up (dry run): `git clean -ndX`
There may be some `.gitignore` which lists `*.xml`; "search in files" helps.