# change path where snapshots are kept using ContextKeeper on VisualStudio 2022

Tags: git, visual-studio-2022, workspace

If somebody uses ContextKeeper (https://contextkeeper.io/) for Visual Studio 2022,
I installed ContextKeeper extension (Mental Snapshot) and it saves it's own data (all snapshots and features) in my git folder.

How can I change that path (.contextkeeper) outside of my local git folder?

When I use the ContextKeeper extension it makes changes to my feature and I don't want that .

As a solution, I could use .gitignore for the folder of this extension but that's something which also must be commited as a change, so no good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ContextKeeper](https://contextkeeper.io/)  currently doesn't support changing the .contextkeeper folder but it's on the [roadmap](https://contextkeeper.io/blog/roadmap-for-2022/). I'm currently working on this feature, and hopefully, it will be available in the next major release.

The simplest workaround is to use `.git/info/exclude` file instead of `.gitignore` - it only applies to your local copy of this repository (local, not shared with others). It could be done on a local or even [global level](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22906950/13022906).
.

Comment: Thank you . 
It worked just fine.

Comment: Thank you  !
It worked just fine.It is very useful. 
It would be nice to have the possibility to edit folder location.
When working with 2 local repositories of the same target repository, it would be nice to use the same folder for ContextKeeper extension, for example.
Good luck!