# Which IntelliJ config files should I save in my dotfiles?

Tags: intellij-idea, dotfiles

I would like to keep my IntelliJ config files in my dotfiles repo but my `~/.IntelliJIdea2016.1` folder weights > 1.3G :(

`~/.IntelliJIdea2016.1/config/` still weights > 215M...

`~/.IntelliJIdea2016.1/config/plugins/` contains lots of binaries... not the best candidates for dotfiles :(

Anyone tried to save IntelliJ config without `Export/Import settings` menu option?

Comment: It looks like the main questions for this are https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968531/what-to-gitignore-from-the-idea-folder and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041154/intellij-idea-9-10-what-folders-to-check-into-or-not-check-into-source-contro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to store IntelliJ config file, just use 
[IDE Settings Sync](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9922-ide-settings-sync) plugin.

See this post: [Better Synchronization of your Settings Across Devices](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2017/09/intellij-idea-2017-3-eap-better-synchronization-of-your-settings-across-devices-and-other-improvements/)

Comment: This won't include version history, will it?

Comment: No it won't :-(

Answer (score 3):

Sadly, it's not simple. The user configuration folders are not well-documented and have historically included a bunch of default junk, which is slowly being stripped out (see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-128660 and https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-163616). The documentation of settings files is also very poor; my request for improvement was declined https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-154157).

I version control my settings. If you request access, you can see it at https://gitlab.com/jcrben-staples/dotfiles-group/dotfiles/tree/master/config/intellij-idea-latest with notes at https://gitlab.com/jcrben-staples/dotfiles-group/dotfiles/tree/master/config/intellij-idea-latest/MY_CONFIG_DOCS.md).

I set up my `.gitignore` to ignore everything by default, and then I whitelist the files that I want. With IntelliJ, I didn't know where to start, so I whitelisted the entire folder and then blacklisted a bunch of the files.

My blacklist doesn't exactly answer your question about what files to *include*, but it does give you an idea of what to exclude. I'll try to update this if I figure out which ones to include at some point, but it's a mishmash of plugin files and such.

Right now the blacklist looks something like this:

```
    # IntelliJ IDEA stuff
    .idea
    !config/intellij-idea-latest/**
    !projects/bi-idea/workspace.xml

    # statistics files
    config/intellij-idea-latest/options/statistics*
    config/intellij-idea-latest/options/feature.usage.statistics.xml
    config/intellij-idea-latest/options/usage.statistics.xml
    config/intellij-idea-latest/options/statistics.application.usages.xml

    # user files ??
    config/intellij-idea-latest/user*

    # other
    config/intellij-idea-latest/options/atlassian-ide-plugin.app.xml
    config/intellij-idea-latest/options/cachedDictionary.xml
    config/intellij-idea-latest/options/customization.xml
    # has my autobracket disable
    config/intellij-idea-latest/options/CodeGlance.xml
    # config/intellij-idea/options/editor.codeinsight.xml
    config/intellij-idea-latest/options/databaseDrivers.xml
    config/intellij-idea-latest/options/debugger.xml
    config/intellij-idea-latest/options/dimensions.xml
    config/intellij-idea-latest/options/extensionsRootType.xml
    config/intellij-idea-latest/options/filetypes.xml
    config/intellij-idea-latest/options/find.xml
    config/intellij-idea-latest/options/find.recents.xml
    config/intellij-idea-latest/options/jdk.table.xml
    config/intellij-idea-latest/options/gemmanager.xml
    config/intellij-idea-latest/options/github_settings.xml
    config/intellij-idea-latest/options/gradle.run.settings.xml
    config/intellij-idea-latest/options/extensionsRootType.xml
    config/intellij-idea-latest/options/hg.xml
    config/intellij-idea-latest/options/ignore.xml
    config/intellij-idea-latest/options/markdown.xml
    config/intellij-idea-latest/options/multimarkdown.local.xml
    config/intellij-idea-latest/options/multimarkdown.shared.xml
    config/intellij-idea-latest/options/options.xml
    config/intellij-idea-latest/options/other.xml
    config/intellij-idea-latest/options/packages.xml
    config/intellij-idea-latest/options/pomodoro.state.xml
    config/intellij-idea-latest/options/project.default.xml
    config/intellij-idea-latest/options/proxy.settings.pwd
    config/intellij-idea-latest/options/recentProjects.xml
    config/intellij-idea-latest/options/recentProjectDirectories.xml
    config/intellij-idea-latest/options/remote-servers.xml
    config/intellij-idea-latest/options/runner.layout.xml
    config/intellij-idea-latest/options/scratches.xml
    config/intellij-idea-latest/options/stubIndex.xml
    config/intellij-idea-latest/options/updates.xml
    config/intellij-idea-latest/options/usageView.xml
    config/intellij-idea-latest/options/vcs.xml
    config/intellij-idea-latest/options/window.manager.xml
    config/intellij-idea-latest/options/window.state.xml

    # turn off those auto-update messages...
    config/intellij-idea-latest/port
    config/intellij-idea-latest/plugins/*
    config/intellij-idea-latest/tasks/*
    config/intellij-idea-latest/extensions/
    config/intellij-idea-latest/jdbc-drivers/*

    # region START UNIGNORE IntelliJ
    !config/intellij-idea-latest/scratches/
    !config/intellij-idea-latest/consoles/
    config/intellij-idea-latest/consoles/.history/*

    # General settings
    # config/intellij-idea-latest/sonarlint/
    config/intellij-idea-latest/javascript/nodejs/**
    # config/intellij-idea-latest/options/editor.codeinsight.xml # has my autobracket disable
    # endregion END UNIGNORE Intellij
```

This leaves fair number of files which are not blacklisted - plus I symlink my `.idea` files sometimes and version control those settings, although `workspace.xml` has a lot of stuff and it changes all the time (see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-163348).

Also, keep your eye out for "Share" buttons like the one shown for a scope below, as these seem to control whether the setting is shared to a configuration.

[image]

The most elegant set up for settings configuration comes from VSCode - hopefully at some point Jetbrains will figure this out and copy them:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can either 'Share settings through a settings repository' or you can 'Share your settings with the Settings Sync plugin'.

More details can be found at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sharing-your-ide-settings.html. If the link ever expires please let me know in the comments below.