# Why Android Studio (3.4) created .gitignore doesn't exclude all `/.idea`?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

Whenever a new Android Studio project is created (I'm using Android Studio 3.4), the `.gitignore` content is as below.

```
*.iml
.gradle
/local.properties
/.idea/caches
/.idea/libraries
/.idea/modules.xml
/.idea/workspace.xml
/.idea/navEditor.xml
/.idea/assetWizardSettings.xml
.DS_Store
/build
/captures
.externalNativeBuild
```

Why isn't entire `/.idea` to be ignore but only the selective few? Are the remaining of any special use?

Comment: There may be important metafata files inside the `.idea` directory. These files may be needed when importing the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some that you generally *want* to check into version control (anything project-specific but not user-specific). See [What to gitignore from the .idea folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968531/what-to-gitignore-from-the-idea-folder) for more information. If you don't want to version control them, you can exclude the whole directory.

Comment: Such as...?  I can't think of anything that I'd want to change on other peoples' machines.

Comment: @ScottBiggs Probably things like the project structure, dependency info, build settings, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Excluding all .idea-data would also exclude gradle.xml

I guess this is important for building.
But I am just guessing.