# Do I put a PyCharm Google App Engine project's IML under version control?

Tags: google-app-engine, version-control, intellij-idea, pycharm

With PyCharm projects there's an .idea directory that holds various project configuration files. The answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041154/intellij-idea-9-10-what-folders-to-check-into-or-not-check-into-source-contro/3041866#comment19914504_3041866) question points to a [FAQ](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-1186) that says the IML file should be under version control. But...

For a Google App Engine project, there are settings such as the path to the GAE SDK that are local-machine specific. Keeping the IML file under version control "breaks the build" every time. On the other hand, there are genuine project-related settings in that file.

Is there a workaround?

Comment: Once Path Variables are supported, things should become better: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-6203.

Answer (score 1):

You could put the GAE SDK in the same directory on all the machines. This only resolves the problem with sdkFolder option.