# What folders should be ignored by Git in an Androidstudio Project

Tags: git, android-studio, gitignore

I am asking me , which folders should be explicitely be ignored by Git in a AndroidStudio Project ?

For example. Should ".idea" be ignored ?

Comment: Please check SO before posting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041154/intellij-idea-9-10-what-folders-to-check-into-or-not-check-into-source-contro

Comment: Generally, you only want to version source code which would be common to anyone working on your project.  If you are a sole contributor, and you are certain this will always be the case, then you can open up a bit and maybe add some local config files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually, you need to add `.idea` directory to your `.gitignore` because it is related to your Android Studio external plugin, except that your always relying on the external plugins for your project.

This is your .gitignore should looks like (based on [Android.gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Android.gitignore), please read the comment):

```
# Built application files
*.apk
*.ap_

# Files for the ART/Dalvik VM
*.dex

# Java class files
*.class

# Generated files
bin/
gen/
out/

# Gradle files
.gradle/
build/

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties

# Proguard folder generated by Eclipse
proguard/

# Log Files
*.log

# Android Studio Navigation editor temp files
.navigation/

# Android Studio captures folder
captures/

# IntelliJ
*.iml
.idea/workspace.xml
.idea/tasks.xml
.idea/gradle.xml
.idea/assetWizardSettings.xml
.idea/dictionaries
.idea/libraries
.idea/caches

# Keystore files
# Uncomment the following line if you do not want to check your keystore files in.
#*.jks

# External native build folder generated in Android Studio 2.2 and later
.externalNativeBuild

# Google Services (e.g. APIs or Firebase)
google-services.json

# Freeline
freeline.py
freeline/
freeline_project_description.json

# fastlane
fastlane/report.xml
fastlane/Preview.html
fastlane/screenshots
fastlane/test_output
fastlane/readme.md

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties

# Windows thumbnail db
Thumbs.db

# Windows desktop.ini
desktop.ini

# Linux configuration file
.directory

# OSX files
.DS_Store

# Don't include your google key, depends on your module name.
/app/google-services.json
/app/src/release/res/values/google_maps_api.xml
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great service.

Answer (score 3):

I use [gitignore.io](http://gitignore.io) to generate my base .gitignore files.

[Here's the one for AndroidStudio](https://www.gitignore.io/api/androidstudio)

```
# Created by https://www.gitignore.io/api/androidstudio

### AndroidStudio ###
# Covers files to be ignored for android development using Android Studio.

# Built application files
*.apk
*.ap_

# Files for the ART/Dalvik VM
*.dex

# Java class files
*.class

# Generated files
bin/
gen/
out/

# Gradle files
.gradle
.gradle/
build/

# Signing files
.signing/

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties

# Proguard folder generated by Eclipse
proguard/

# Log Files
*.log

# Android Studio
/*/build/
/*/local.properties
/*/out
/*/*/build
/*/*/production
captures/
.navigation/
*.ipr
*~
*.swp

# Android Patch
gen-external-apklibs

# External native build folder generated in Android Studio 2.2 and later
.externalNativeBuild

# NDK
obj/

# IntelliJ IDEA
*.iml
*.iws
/out/

# User-specific configurations
.idea/caches/
.idea/libraries/
.idea/shelf/
.idea/workspace.xml
.idea/tasks.xml
.idea/.name
.idea/compiler.xml
.idea/copyright/profiles_settings.xml
.idea/encodings.xml
.idea/misc.xml
.idea/modules.xml
.idea/scopes/scope_settings.xml
.idea/dictionaries
.idea/vcs.xml
.idea/jsLibraryMappings.xml
.idea/datasources.xml
.idea/dataSources.ids
.idea/sqlDataSources.xml
.idea/dynamic.xml
.idea/uiDesigner.xml

# OS-specific files
.DS_Store
.DS_Store?
._*
.Spotlight-V100
.Trashes
ehthumbs.db
Thumbs.db

# Legacy Eclipse project files
.classpath
.project
.cproject
.settings/

# Mobile Tools for Java (J2ME)
.mtj.tmp/

# Package Files #
*.war
*.ear

# virtual machine crash logs (Reference: http://www.java.com/en/download/help/error_hotspot.xml)
hs_err_pid*

## Plugin-specific files:

# mpeltonen/sbt-idea plugin
.idea_modules/

# JIRA plugin
atlassian-ide-plugin.xml

# Mongo Explorer plugin
.idea/mongoSettings.xml

# Crashlytics plugin (for Android Studio and IntelliJ)
com_crashlytics_export_strings.xml
crashlytics.properties
crashlytics-build.properties
fabric.properties

### AndroidStudio Patch ###

!/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar


# End of https://www.gitignore.io/api/androidstudio
```

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio will automatically generate a .gitignore file when choosing a local git repository as destination folder when creating a project.

On my machine, it looks like this:

```
*.iml
.gradle
/local.properties
/.idea/caches
/.idea/libraries
/.idea/modules.xml
/.idea/workspace.xml
/.idea/navEditor.xml
/.idea/assetWizardSettings.xml
.DS_Store
/build
/captures
.externalNativeBuild
.cxx
```